# What is $\sup_{s \in (y,1)} (y-s)^{m} \cdot \frac{m!}{s^{m+1}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, supremum-and-infimum

Is there a clever way to evaluate
$$\sup_{s \in (y,1)} (y-s)^{m} \cdot \frac{m!}{s^{m+1}}$$
$ y \in\mathbb{R}, \space\space\space 0< y\leq 1$?

I suspect it is $(y-1)^{m} \cdot m! $, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Have you tried differentiating?

Comment: you mean evaluate $\frac{d}{ds}[ (y-s)^{m} \cdot \frac{m!}{s^{m+1}}]$ ?

Comment: Yes. since the function is obviously defined and continuously differentiable, its supremum on $(y,1)$ will be its maximum on $[y,1]$, which either occurs at the endpoints or at a point where the derivative is $0$.

Comment: My calculation yields a critical point at $s = \frac{y}{1-m}$. Is that correct?